# 'date is an invalid date or time string' when passing form data to URL - ColdFusion

Tags: forms, url, coldfusion

I'm trying to pass data from the mobiscroll jquery datepicker to a mySQL query in ColdFusion. When i post the form it just sends the input name and not what is actually there. The yo variable appears as 'date' and I get this error message. " date is an invalid date or time string. " This is the code:

```
 <form action="searchWED.cfm?sorter=date&yo=date" method="post">
<input type="text" name="date" id="SubmitDate" class="i-txt">
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>


<cfif IsDefined("URL.yo")>
```

Comment: To keep things simple, I avoid adding query strings to form action attributes.  Anything that can be put into a query string can also be made a hidden form field, which is what I do.  That way, on the action page, I only have to deal with variables from one scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're POSTing the form, so the form fields are translated to FORM scoped variables. They would only exist in the URL scope if you submitted the form using `method="GET"`.

So `URL.sorter` and `URL.yo` exist, but you'll have to check for `form.date` for the date value.

Comment: If the intent was to send a date value as url.yo, it might be missing octothorps.  Something like searchWED.cfm?sorter=date&yo=#date#, where date was a variable somewhere else on that page.

Comment: Date is just coming from the form. Is there way to make it into a CF variable?

Comment: Yes, read the second paragraph of this answer.  If that's not clear, cfdump your form at the start of searchWED.cfm.

Comment: Hi, I changed the variable 'yo' to 'date and on cfdumping the form I get '2013-02-21,Submit Query' But it still won't feed into my query.